# $f \in L^1$ differentiable almost everywhere with $f' \in L^1$ implies $f$ has weak derivative $f'$?

Tags: weak-convergence

I got a function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f \in L^1(a,b)$. It is differentiable a.e. with derivative $f' \in L^1(a,b)$.

How can I show that $f$ has a weak derivative?

I know that $\int f\varphi'$ and $-\int f' \varphi$ both make sense but why they are equal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, what you are asking is wrong. To see this, recall that (in dimension 1) every function with a weak derivative is (locally absolutely) continuous (has such a representative).

But if we take e.g. $f = \chi_{[0,2]}$, then $f$ is differentiable a.e., but has no continuous version, hence has no weak derivative.

You can even see this explicitly: the derivative if $f$ is $f' =0$ a.e., but

$$
\int f \cdot \varphi' dx = \int_0^2 \varphi' dx = \varphi(2) - \varphi(0) \neq 0=  \int f' \cdot \varphi dx 
$$
for suitable $\varphi \in C_c^\infty$.

EDIT: the claim also remains false if $f$ is assumed to be continuous. A counter example is provided by the Cantor function (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), which is an increasing, continuous function that is differentiable a.e. (with derivative $0$), but **not absolutely continuous**; hence, it has no weak derivative.

Comment: Thanks. Does it change if $f$ is cts?

Comment: If you mean continuous by "cts", then the claim remains false, see my edit above.

Comment: Oh I forgot about Cantor function. Thanks a lot.